# Detect multiple headers in CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-processing

I have a large csv file. Inside the csv file there are several headers. I've separated the three headers using code as below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("three measurement.csv", header=None)

# find header rows
df_titles = ["Level and Distortion", "THD Ratio", "Reference Waveform"]
# create groups for each section
groupings = df.iloc[:, 0].str.contains("|".join(df_titles)).cumsum()

# split into new dataframes as dictionary
d = {}
for i, j in df.groupby(groupings):
    # define name of dictionary key as title, and set data of DF as values
    d[j.iloc[0, 0]] = pd.DataFrame(data=j.values[4:, :],
                                   # create MultiIndex from 3 header rows
                                   columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
                                       j.iloc[0:4, :].ffill(axis=1).values))
    # suggested not to use, but you can set the variables directly (outside of the dictionary)
    globals()[j.iloc[0, 0]] = pd.DataFrame(data=j.values[4:, :],
                                           columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
                                               j.iloc[0:4, :].ffill(axis=1).values))
```

`Level and Distortion`, `THD Ratio`, and `Reference Waveform` are the types of measurements that I have separated. But the measurement type can change (increase or decrease) how to detect the measurement type without specifying the measurement type as in the code above (`df_titles=[".."`). This means that in the code above to find the header line, you have to specify the names of the measurement types according to the csv that I show below. If the measurement type is different and increasing, how do I find the header row without having to define the df_title variable.
Here CSV File

```
"Level and Distortion",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
"Ch1 (F)",,"Ch1 (H2)",,"Ch1 (H3)",,"Ch1 (Total)",,"Ch2 (F)",,"Ch2 (H2)",,"Ch2 (H3)",,"Ch2 (Total)",
X,Y,X,Y,X,Y,X,Y,X,Y,X,Y,X,Y,X,Y
Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms
20,0.00772013164376534,20,5.60982648239952E-05,20,0.000389709733151927,20,0.011492581958802,20,0.00699792689186063,20,0.000151471712877565,20,0.000389940899485093,20,0.010080448380793
21.1179638886716,0.00747175133180212,21.1179638886716,8.83327496082501E-05,21.1179638886716,0.000426696028852445,21.1179638886716,0.0122462876404656,21.1179638886716,0.00756340531214287,21.1179638886716,0.000181697169530165,21.1179638886716,0.000443499862648762,21.1179638886716,0.0108494276048029
"THD Ratio",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Ch1,,Ch2,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,Y,X,Y,,,,,,,,,,,,
Hz,%,Hz,%,,,,,,,,,,,,
20,83.009797319554,20,82.1460991930652,,,,,,,,,,,,
21.1179638886716,85.3656629417084,21.1179638886716,82.0338466400102,,,,,,,,,,,,
22.2984199401618,90.6674826441566,22.2984199401618,85.7190774666039,,,,,,,,,,,,
"Reference Waveform",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Ch1,,Ch2,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,Y,X,Y,,,,,,,,,,,,
s,V,s,V,,,,,,,,,,,,
0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,
2.08333333333333E-05,6.47890208369956E-08,2.08333333333333E-05,6.47890208369956E-08,,,,,,,,,,,,
4.16666666666667E-05,5.18304721721536E-07,4.16666666666667E-05,5.18304721721536E-07,,,,,,,,,,,,
6.25E-05,1.74923655865586E-06,6.25E-05,1.74923655865586E-06,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Actually there are a lot of row data in the csv file.

Because the type of measurement can change (increase or decrease) there are 11 types of measurement. I want python to be able to detect the measurement type without having to define it like `df_titles = ["Level and Distortion", "THD Ratio", "Reference Waveform"]`.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it true that a row with measurement type only contains the type in the first column and no data in all other columns? Is it also true that all other rows contain data in at least one column that isn't the first one?

Comment: Yes, that's all true.

Comment: One more all the headers of each type of measurement type of all rows are the same as in the examples

Comment: I think the examples I've shown represent all types of sizes

Comment: The measurement type line is located in the first row of each measurement data. like the csv example that I showed there are 3 types of brackets

Comment: Not concatenating the CSV files into one big unhappy file in the first place would seem like the obvious workaround.

Comment: @tripleee The file is the output of a measurement software that I use

Comment: I think changing the data is a bad idea

Comment: (Then that measurement software is arguably broken, but okay.)

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to ask, though. Which measurements exactly are "increasing or decreasing" and what is your expected output?

Comment: In the csv file that I saw above `Level and Distortion`, `THD Ratio` and `Reference Waveform` are measurement types. And these measurements can be increased or decreased, for example there is an addition of the `phase` measurement type and others.

Comment: in the above script (`df_title`) we have to define the measurement type to get the dataframe for each measurement type. Since the measurement type can be "increased or decreased" I want `df_title` to be able to detect the measurement type without having to define it like the code I've shown above.

Comment: Split your dataframe if you detect a row with only one value. After that split your data in 2 parts. String rows are headers (multiindex), numeric rows are data. Check my answer below. (And don't use `globals` to create variables because `Level and distortion` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: This is not a true CSV file, and IMHO Pandas is not the best tool to process it. But you have neither describe the exact file structure, nor shown the expected data, so I cannot show you how to process that through the lower level csv module.

Comment: Please don't hide details down here in the comments; [edit] your question to contain all pertinent information about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.read_csv` with right parameters:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('three measurement.csv', dtype='str', header=None, keep_default_na=False, na_values='')

dfs = {}
idx = df.index[df.notna().sum(axis=1).eq(1)].tolist()
for i, j in zip(idx, idx[1:]+[len(df)]):
    name = df.loc[i, 0]
    df1 = df.loc[i+1:j-1].dropna(how='all', axis=1).replace('N/A', np.nan)
    m = pd.to_numeric(df1[0], errors='coerce').notna()
    mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df1.loc[~m].ffill(axis=1).values)
    dfs[name] = pd.DataFrame(df1.loc[m].values.astype(float), columns=mi)
```

Output:

```
>>> list(dfs.keys())
['Level and Distortion',
 'THD Ratio',
 'Reference Waveform',
 'Summary: Signal Path1.Acoustic Response.Level and Distortion',
 'Summary: Signal Path1.Acoustic Response.THD Ratio',
 'Summary: Signal Path1.Acoustic Response.Reference Waveform']

>>> dfs['Level and Distortion']
          Ch1 (F)             Ch1 (H2)             Ch1 (H3)           Ch1 (Total)                 Ch2 (F)             Ch2 (H2)             Ch2 (H3)           Ch2 (Total)          
                X         Y          X         Y          X         Y           X         Y             X         Y          X         Y          X         Y           X         Y
               Hz      Vrms         Hz      Vrms         Hz      Vrms          Hz      Vrms            Hz      Vrms         Hz      Vrms         Hz      Vrms          Hz      Vrms
0       20.000000  0.007720  20.000000  0.000056  20.000000  0.000390   20.000000  0.011493     20.000000  0.006998  20.000000  0.000151  20.000000  0.000390   20.000000  0.010080
1       21.117964  0.007472  21.117964  0.000088  21.117964  0.000427   21.117964  0.012246     21.117964  0.007563  21.117964  0.000182  21.117964  0.000443   21.117964  0.010849
2       22.298420  0.005521  22.298420  0.000107  22.298420  0.000408   22.298420  0.011866     22.298420  0.007572  22.298420  0.000209  22.298420  0.000505   22.298420  0.012603
3       23.544861  0.007055  23.544861  0.000269  23.544861  0.000313   23.544861  0.012183     23.544861  0.007603  23.544861  0.000227  23.544861  0.000568   23.544861  0.012779
4       24.860977  0.008749  24.860977  0.000260  24.860977  0.000653   24.860977  0.013460     24.860977  0.005882  24.860977  0.000217  24.860977  0.000364   24.860977  0.013626
..            ...       ...        ...       ...        ...       ...         ...       ...           ...       ...        ...       ...        ...       ...         ...       ...
123  16089.472533  0.060342        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN  16089.472533  0.061988        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN
124  16988.844997  0.059465        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN  16988.844997  0.047697        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN
125  17938.490757  0.036990        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN  17938.490757  0.035544        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN
126  18941.220002  0.061363        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN  18941.220002  0.050418        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN
127  20000.000000  0.064279        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN  20000.000000  0.059796        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN

[128 rows x 16 columns]

>>> dfs['THD Ratio']
              Ch1                      Ch2           
                X          Y             X          Y
               Hz          %            Hz          %
0       20.000000  83.009797     20.000000  82.146099
1       21.117964  85.365663     21.117964  82.033847
2       22.298420  90.667483     22.298420  85.719077
3       23.544861  86.536381     23.544861  85.941987
4       24.860977  83.845657     24.860977  91.810750
..            ...        ...           ...        ...
112   8845.029526  58.356075   8845.029526  37.976407
113   9339.450707  32.391086   9339.450707  58.039594
114   9861.509138  34.756184   9861.509138  38.396633
115  10412.749693  31.359953  10412.749693  20.900020
116  10994.803600  35.219231  10994.803600  26.008255

[117 rows x 4 columns]

>>> dfs['Reference Waveform']
              Ch1                      Ch2              
                X             Y          X             Y
                s             V          s             V
0        0.000000  0.000000e+00   0.000000  0.000000e+00
1        0.000021  6.478902e-08   0.000021  6.478902e-08
2        0.000042  5.183047e-07   0.000042  5.183047e-07
3        0.000063  1.749237e-06   0.000063  1.749237e-06
4        0.000083  4.146200e-06   0.000083  4.146200e-06
...           ...           ...        ...           ...
719994  14.999875  3.035885e-08  14.999875  3.035885e-08
719995  14.999896 -7.711807e-09  14.999896 -7.711807e-09
719996  14.999917  2.917104e-10  14.999917  2.917104e-10
719997  14.999937  3.821995e-10  14.999937  3.821995e-10
719998  14.999958 -4.497611e-11  14.999958 -4.497611e-11

[719999 rows x 4 columns]

>>> dfs['Summary: Signal Path1.Acoustic Response.Level and Distortion']
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(Channel, Ch1, Ch2), (Passed Lower Limit, Ch1, Ch2), (Passed Upper Limit, Ch1, Ch2)]
Index: []

>>> dfs['Summary: Signal Path1.Acoustic Response.THD Ratio']
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(Channel, Ch1, Ch2), (Passed Lower Limit, Ch1, Ch2), (Passed Upper Limit, Ch1, Ch2)]
Index: []

>>> dfs['Summary: Signal Path1.Acoustic Response.Reference Waveform']
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(Channel, Ch1, Ch2), (Passed Lower Limit, Ch1, Ch2), (Passed Upper Limit, Ch1, Ch2)]
Index: []
```

Concat all dataframes:

```
>>> pd.concat(dfs, names=['Measurement'], axis=1)

Measurement Level and Distortion                                 ... Summary: Signal Path1.Acoustic Response.THD Ratio Summary: Signal Path1.Acoustic Response.Reference Waveform                                      
                         Ch1 (F)             Ch1 (H2)            ...                                Passed Upper Limit                                                    Channel Passed Lower Limit Passed Upper Limit
                               X         Y          X         Y  ...                                               Ch1                                                        Ch1                Ch1                Ch1
                              Hz      Vrms         Hz      Vrms  ...                                               Ch2                                                        Ch2                Ch2                Ch2
0                      20.000000  0.007720  20.000000  0.000056  ...                                               NaN                                                NaN                        NaN                NaN
1                      21.117964  0.007472  21.117964  0.000088  ...                                               NaN                                                NaN                        NaN                NaN
2                      22.298420  0.005521  22.298420  0.000107  ...                                               NaN                                                NaN                        NaN                NaN
3                      23.544861  0.007055  23.544861  0.000269  ...                                               NaN                                                NaN                        NaN                NaN
4                      24.860977  0.008749  24.860977  0.000260  ...                                               NaN                                                NaN                        NaN                NaN
...                          ...       ...        ...       ...  ...                                               ...                                                ...                        ...                ...
719994                       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN  ...                                               NaN                                                NaN                        NaN                NaN
719995                       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN  ...                                               NaN                                                NaN                        NaN                NaN
719996                       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN  ...                                               NaN                                                NaN                        NaN                NaN
719997                       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN  ...                                               NaN                                                NaN                        NaN                NaN
719998                       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN  ...                                               NaN                                                NaN                        NaN                NaN

[719999 rows x 33 columns]
```